# l3keys: how to store the value of a choice key more effectively?

Tags: expl3, l3keys

I want to define with l3keys a choice key which also stores the value given to the key. That's easy enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \curmykey

\keys_define:nn { my }
 {
 mykey .choice:,
 mykey /choice-a .code:n ={\tl_set:Nn\curmykey{#1}spezific~code~for~a},
 mykey /choice-b .code:n ={\tl_set:Nn\curmykey{#1}spezific~code~for~b},
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_set:nn{my}{mykey=choice-a,},~\curmykey
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

But I don't find it very elegant to have to copy the `\tl_set:Nn\curmykey{#1}` in all the code arguments. Is there any way to define \curmykey only in one place? (I already tried `mykey .tl_set:N` but this breaks the choice code.)

Comment: I don't understand the question (it's probably me, but if you could rephrase the question or detail it alittle bit more I would appreciate it). In any case, the key name and value are stored in `\l_keys_key_tl` and  `\l_keys_value_tl` (and there's also `\l_keys_choice_tl`). I'm not sure what do you want to do.

Comment: @Manuel: I have two `\tl_set:Nn\curmykey{#1}` above in the code, and each choice would need one more. I want to avoid this repetition. `\l_keys_value_tl` is not an option: it holds the value after the setting of the key but as I need it much later on I must store this value in some other command before it is overwritten by some other key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\keys_define:nn { my }
 {
  mykey .code:n =
    \tl_set_eq:NN \curmykey \l_keys_value_tl \keys_set:nn { my } { mykeyaux = #1 } ,
  mykeyaux .choice: ,
  mykeyaux / choice-a .code:n = { spezific ~ code ~ for ~ a } ,
  mykeyaux / choice-b .code:n = { spezific ~ code ~ for ~ b } ,
 }
```

Comment: Ulrike, if this doesn't work please, let me know, and I will delete it. I can't compile right know, so this is a “theoretical answer”.

Comment: Good idea. One should add a specific error message for `mykeyaux / unknown .code:n =` so that users are not confused when they use unknown choices and get a complain about the key "mykeyaux".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Those messages and warnings are out of my knowledge, if you want to edit this answer, feel free to do it.